# How can I remove dynamically added join() divider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyup

I'm trying to achieve exact same result as here : https://veeva-subject-lines.tomasino.org/

It is using vue.js, but I'm looking for a simple jquery or javascript solution. Here's what I've managed to do so far :

In a keyup function, I create an array of all inputs value, separated by a "|". All inputs values are displayed in a "result" div. Then, with an "add" or "remove" buttons,  I add a new input with specific ID, or I delete the added input.

**What I'm trying to achieve** :

The '|" divider is added with join() function. When deleting an input and associated text in the restult div, the divider is still there. How can I delete it ?

Here is my code :

```js
    $('body').on('input', '.custom', function(event) {
        var tokens='';
        var i = 0;
        var token = $('.custom').map(function() {
           i++;
          return '<span id="custom-'+ i +'">' + this.value + '</span>';
        }).get().join('|');
        tokens += token;
          $('#token').html(tokens);
          //remove related input value in the result div
          $('.remove').click(function(){
            $('#custom-'+ i +'').remove();
            i--;
          });       
    });    
    // I add a new input on add click, with a specific ID starting from 3 as there are already two harcoded input
    var count = 3;
    $('.add').click(function() {
      var y = '<div class="flex-row"><label><input id="custom_text_' + (count++) + '" class="custom" type="text" name="" placeholder="custom text"></label><button class="remove">-</button>';
      $(y).insertBefore('.add');
    });
    $('body').on('click','.remove', function(){
      $(this).parent('.flex-row').remove();
      

      
    })
  });
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <article>
        <section>
          <div class="flex-row">
            <label for="custom_text_one"><input id="custom_text_1" class="custom" type="text" name="" placeholder="custom text"></label>
            <button class="remove">-</button>
          </div>

          <div class="flex-row">
            <label for="custom_text_two"><input id="custom_text_2" class="custom" type="text" name="" placeholder="custom text 2"></label>
            <button class="remove">-</button>
          </div>
          <button class="add">+</button>
          <div class="flex-row">
            <div>customText{{[<span id="token"></span>]}}</div>
          </div>
        </section>
      </article>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-aVKKRRi/Q/YV+4mjoKBsE4x3H+BkegoM/em46NNlCqNTmUYADjBbeNefNxYV7giUp0VxICtqdrbqU7iVaeZNXA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
</body>
```

**EDIT** : thanks to Twisty I managed to add the remove function, and now I can also delete inputs and outputs together..
here is the final code :

```
     $("#inputs").on('input', 'input[type=text]', function(event) {
  
    var i = $(this).closest(".flex-row").index();
    var v = (i == 0) ? $(this).val() : "|" + $(this).val();
    $("#custom_wrapper .output").eq(i).html(v);
  });


  $('.add').click(function() {
    var count = $("#inputs input").length;
    count++;
    var row = $("<div>", {
      class: "flex-row"
    }).insertBefore(this);
    $("<label>").appendTo(row);
    $("<input>", {
      type: "text",
      class: "input",
      placeholder: "custom text " + count,
      id:"custom-text-" +count,
      tabindex: count
    }).appendTo($("label", row));
    $("<button>", {
      class: "remove"
    }).html("-").appendTo(row);
    $("<span>", {
      class: "output",
      dataid:"custom-text-" +count,
    }).insertAfter($("#custom_wrapper .output:last"));
  });
  
  $('body').on('click','.remove', function(){
      $(this).parent('.flex-row').remove();  
      var j =$(this).parent().find('.input').attr("id");
      $('#custom_wrapper .output[dataid="'+ j +'"').empty();
      
      
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `.html()` instead of `.append()`.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".container").on('input', 'input[type=text]', function(event) {
    var i = $(this).closest(".flex-row").index();
    var v = (i == 0) ? $(this).val() : "|" + $(this).val();
    $("#custom_wrapper .output").eq(i).html(v);
  });

  $('.add').click(function() {
    var count = $("input").length;
    count++;
    var row = $("<div>", {
      class: "flex-row"
    }).insertBefore(this);
    $("<label>").appendTo(row);
    $("<input>", {
      type: "text",
      class: "input",
      placeholder: "custom text " + count,
      tabindex: count
    }).appendTo($("label", row));
    $("<button>", {
      class: "remove"
    }).html("-").appendTo(row);
    $("<span>", {
      class: "output"
    }).insertAfter($("#custom_wrapper .output:last"));
  });
});
```

```css
.flex-row label {
  padding-right: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <article>
      <section>
        <div class="flex-row">
          <label><input class="input" type="text" name="" placeholder="custom text" tabindex="1" /></label><button class="remove">-</button>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-row">
          <label><input class="input" type="text" name="" placeholder="custom text 2" tabindex="2"></label><button class="remove">-</button>
        </div>
        <button class="add">+</button>
        <div class="flex-row">
          <div>customText{{[<span id="custom_wrapper"><span class="output"></span><span class="output"></span></span>]}}</div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </article>
  </div>
</div>
```

This adds text to from your `input` to specific parts of your string, separating `output` with the pipe character (`|`). Each `input` corresponds to an `output`.

Comment: In fact, in the link I'm referencing, the textarea is already populated by some kind of placeholder customText{{[customText1|custometext2|custometext3 ]}}. When the user fills in the first text field, it replaces the "customtext1" in the placeholder above. When filling in the second text field, it replaces "customtext2" in the placeholder above. And so on. And when he adds a line, it adds a "customtextx" in the placeholder.. that's what I would like to achieve. In your example, the inserted text replaces the previous one, which doesn't work for me..

Comment: @blogob I updated my answer after your comment.

Comment: thank you so much Twisty, finaly I used your  code to delete inputs and associated output and it seems to work well..inside the input function I added : $('.remove').click(function(){  var is = $(this).closest(".flex-row").index(); var ve =  $(this).val();  $("#custom_wrapper .output").eq(is).remove(ve); }). Do you think it's ok like this ? I eddited my code with your answer

Comment: @blogob yes that should work to remove a specific output.

Comment: thank  you very much Twisty, I accepted your answer as the solution !!

Comment: after some tests, I realized that the deletion works, but only if we delete in order (3,2,1 etc). If for example I create 4 inputs, and I delete the second one first, it bugs, and once everything is deleted, I can no longer insert text into the inputs.. Twisity If you ever have a solution, I will be delighted!

Comment: @blogob I would suggest checking for errors in the console. If you need more help, since this is a new issue, maybe post a new question.